# Turn on browser caching per site

Tags: windows-server-2003, cache, internet-explorer, group-policy

We have a windows 2003 AD domain users use IE6 clients.

Browser caching is turned off as a domain policy.

Question is: Is it possible to override this for a group of users for a specific web site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group Policy objects linked to Active Directory Sites (assuming you're talking about an AD Site) are processed second, right after Local Group Policy. This means that any domain-level (or lower, OU-level) GPOs will "override" them by default. You could tick the "No Override" setting on the site-level GPO such that it "overrides" the domain-level GPO that has the unwanted setting.

If your computers aren't arranged into AD Sites and you're using the term "site" somewhat more generically then you'll probably be stuck creating a security group that contains the affected computers and either denying those computers the right to apply the GPO with the unwanted settings or creating a GPO that "undoes" the unwanted setting and allowing only those computers the rights to apply the new GPO.

Edit:

Thanks for the edit.

There is no method to make IE maintain a cache for only specific web sites. The cache settings aren't tied to the "security zones", etc.

Comment: +1 Thanks, I have updated the question to make it a little clearer